# Correct syntax for Range(Cells(),Cells())

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie to VBA and look like similar code with heading VBA script to copy adjacent cells if duplicate found

```
Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 2)).Copy
```

This selects **Column B** and paste in adjacent cell C, but i would be needing to select B:D and paste in E:G until duplicate found.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573778/how-can-i-copy-a-row-of-data-and-paste-it-with-an-offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(a, b))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) Selects all the cells from x,y in the top left to a,b in the bottom right.  However, the syntax is a little odd because the ROW comes first (x or a) and the COLUMN comes second (y or b).  Therefore your `2` in both `Cells()` is indicating column `B`.  Simply change it to a `4` in the second `Cells()` to select from `B:D`.

```
Range(Cells(firstInstanceRow + 1, 2), Cells(lastInstanceRow, 4)).Copy
```

Comment: Thanks @Chrismas007 tried your way it didnt work for me, I have reposted my required, please have a look and help me out.

Comment: @IvrameshKannan I'd recommend leaving this question the way you originally asked and reasking the question with your new criteria.  Rewriting the question now won't get any new views.  I'll revert your question back to the original and I'd suggest asking a new Q.

Comment: Thanks @chrismas007